# Seeing the real numbers as a $\mathbb{C}$-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, ideals

I recently bumped into [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506684/can-we-make-the-real-numbers-a-mathbbc-module) question on the community and the accepted answer left me thinking. I always thought that we couldn't view the real numbers as a $\mathbb{C}$-module for the following reason. Any ring is a module over itself. Therefore, in a ring $R$, the left $R$-modules are exactly the left $R$-ideals. Now if we take the ring $(\mathbb{C},+, \cdot)$ with the usual addition and product, $\mathbb{R}$ is not an ideal of this ring. Therefore, if it is not a $\mathbb{C}$-ideal, it cannot be a $\mathbb{C}$-module. Where is my reasoning wrong? Perhaps I need to define different operations in the ring?

Comment: "The left $R$-modules are exactly the left $R$-ideals." Not true. Presumably you mean the submodules of $R,$ treated as a left $R$-module, are exactly...

Comment: Modules over a field are called **vector spaces**.

Answer (score 3):

$\Bbb R$ is not a $\Bbb C$-submodule of $\Bbb C$ for the reasons you provide.

There is, however, a $\Bbb C$-module structure on the abelian group $\Bbb R$.

These two statements don't contradict each other. The fact that $\Bbb R$ is a subset of $\Bbb C$ may be misleading here, it's irrelevant for the existence of a $\Bbb C$-module structure.

Here's an easier example of the same phenomenon: consider $\Bbb Q[T]/(T^2)$ and the subgroup $\Bbb Q \subset \Bbb Q[T]/(T^2)$. It's not a submodule, because it's not an ideal, but still $\Bbb Q$ can be given a $\Bbb Q[T]/(T^2)$-structure. (Do you see how?)

Comment: What does it mean to have a $\mathbb{C}$-module structure?

Comment: @kubo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)#Formal_definition

Comment: And also, in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/506874/758031) answer they construct the morphism between $\mathbb{C}$ and End$(\mathbb{R})$, which is the necessary condition for being a $\mathbb{C}$ module, right?

Comment: You have used the expression “$\Bbb C$-module” in your question. Are you claiming that you don't understand what it means?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I do understand it. However, I do not understand the difference between being a $\mathbb{C}$-module and having a $\mathbb{C}$-module structure

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos if it is not a $\mathbb{C}$-module, how can it have a $\mathbb{C}$-module structure?

Comment: No. Being a $\Bbb C$-module and having a $\Bbb C$-module structure are the same thing.

Comment: @kubo please read my answer closely. I was saying that $\Bbb R$ is not a $\Bbb C$-**sub**module of $\Bbb C$. That's something else than saying it's not a $\Bbb C$-module. (Which I never claimed)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are confusing modules and submodules. $\mathbb R$ can be given structure of a $\mathbb C$-module, but that module can't be submodule of $\mathbb C$. But these are two different things. There are many $\mathbb C$-modules $M$ that are not submodules of $\mathbb C$. For example, take $M$ to be space of functions $\{f\colon X\to\mathbb C\}$, then you can define $(z\cdot f)(x) = zf(x)$, where on the RHS we have multiplication in $\mathbb C$. Clearly, that's not a submodule of $\mathbb C$. The fact that $\mathbb R$ is a subset of $\mathbb C$ is irrelevant, we can define how $\mathbb C$ acts on $\mathbb R$ in other ways than by multiplication in $\mathbb C$.

However, this is not a straightforward thing to do, but we can do it. I'll use the fact that $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ are isomorphic as abelian groups (you can see why [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/337121/122131)). Let $\varphi\colon (\mathbb R,+)\to (\mathbb C,+)$ be a group isomorphism and let's define $$z\cdot x = \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x)),\ z\in\mathbb C,\ x\in\mathbb R.$$
This defines $\mathbb C$-module structure on $\mathbb R$:

\begin{align}z\cdot(x+y)&=\varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x+y)) = \varphi^{-1}(z(\varphi(x)+\varphi(y)))=\varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x)+z\varphi(y))\\ &= \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x))+\varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(y)) =z\cdot x + z\cdot y\end{align}

\begin{align}
(z+w)\cdot x &=\varphi^{-1}((z+w)\varphi(x)) = \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x) +w\varphi(x)) = \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(x))+ \varphi^{-1}(w\varphi(x))\\ &= z\cdot x + w\cdot x
\end{align}

\begin{align}z\cdot(w\cdot x) = \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(w\cdot x)) = \varphi^{-1}(z\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(w\varphi(x)))) = \varphi^{-1}(zw\varphi(x)) = (zw)\cdot x\end{align}

$$1\cdot x = \varphi^{-1}(1\varphi(x)) = \varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)) = x.$$

Comment: Hi Ennar. I would like to talk to you about the comment you have recently posted on the question you cite in this answer. You say that the ring homomorphism isn't multiplicative (and thus not an isomorphism). I have however proved that it is multiplicative, although I may be mistaken, of course. I would like to discuss this with you, but I am afraid the comment section is too short for this. Any idea on how could we do it?

Comment: @kubo, oof, that was a mistake, I wanted to post different link, sorry about that. I wrote in that comment precisely why it can't be multiplicative: $\phi(a)\phi(i) \neq \phi(i)\phi(a)$, but $\phi(ai) = \phi(ia)$ since $\mathbb C$ is commutative. In general, the image of a ring homomorphism with commutative domain is commutative, but subring generated by $\langle \phi_a,f \mid a\in\mathbb R\rangle$ in $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb R)$ is not commutative. Let me quickly look up correct link.

Comment: What I don't get from your comment is that you state that $\phi(ia)=\phi(i)\circ \phi(a)$, and I don't see why this is true

Comment: @Kubo what's the multiplication in $\mathrm{End}(\mathbb R)$? Note that if you want to define action of $\mathbb C$ on $\mathbb R$, you define $z\cdot x$, and then you need to have $(zw)\cdot x = z\cdot(w\cdot x)$. But, that's the same as defining homomorphism $\phi\colon \mathbb C\to \mathrm{End}(\mathbb R)$ and the link is $\phi(z)(x) = z\cdot x$, and $(zw)\cdot x = z\cdot(w\cdot x)$ is the same as $\phi(zw) = \phi(z)\circ \phi(w)$.

Comment: @Kubo, also just read the definition in the answer there, it says $\phi(a+bi) = \phi_a + \phi_b\circ f$. Therefore, $\phi(a) = \phi_a, \phi(i) = f$ and $\phi(ai) = \phi(0+ai) = \phi_a\circ f$.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. Could you then please try to spot where is my mistake in this proof? I would be very grateful. [Click here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0a88dfbc8ac9945f6d8748a07cee5b5e20230724150014/5119dc)

Comment: @kubo, the mistake is in the last step: $\phi(a+bi)\phi(c+di) = (\phi_a+\phi_b f)(\phi_c+\phi_d f) = \phi_a \phi_c+\phi_a\phi_d f + \phi_b f \phi_c +\phi_b f \phi_d f$. I used concatenation to denote composition to get rid of too much $\circ$'s. Maybe it will be more clear to you if you apply functions $\phi((a+bi)(c+di))$ and $\phi(a+bi)\circ\phi(c+di)$ on some real number $x$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147446/discussion-between-kubo-and-ennar).

Comment: Let me mention that this answer shows how to *transport* a structure via an isomorphism. This is a standart technique in abstract algebra. (+1)